# DB2 JOIN, UNION, and pull max value from each group

Tags: sql, db2, union

I am having a difficult time wrapping my head around the path for solving a problem in DB2.  I have three tables that look like this...

**PARENT**

```
id | label
--------------
 1 | One
 2 | Two        
 3 | Three
```

**TABLE1**

```
id | parentid | eventdate
-------------------------
 1 | 1        | 2015-11-01
 2 | 1        | 2015-12-01
 3 | 2        | 2015-10-01
 4 | 2        | 2015-09-01
 5 | 3        | 2015-08-01
 6 | 3        | 2015-07-01
```

**TABLE2**

```
id | parentid | eventdate
-------------------------
 1 | 1        | 2015-11-15
 2 | 1        | 2015-12-15
 3 | 2        | 2015-07-15
 4 | 2        | 2015-09-15
 5 | 3        | 2015-08-15
 6 | 3        | 2015-05-15
```

Ultimately, I need to find the max date from either table for each parent id.  My thought is to UNION two SELECTs, each being JOINed to PARENT, but I am at a complete loss as to how to only pull back a single row for each parent that consists of the max date from either TABLE1 or TABLE2 like this:

```
One: 2015-12-15
Two: 2015-10-01
Three: 2015-08-15
```

If anyone could offer some guidance I would be extremely grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. Use a union in a subquery and then join PARENT and GROUP BY label to get the MAX date.

```
SELECT label, MAX(eventdate) AS maxeventdate FROM (
  SELECT parentid, eventdate FROM TABLE1
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT parentid, eventdate FROM TABLE2)
JOIN PARENT ON (id = parentid)
GROUP BY label
```

Comment: Thank you.  That was exactly what I was going for!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT label,
       CASE WHEN max(t1.eventdate) > max(t2.eventdate) 
                 THEN max(t1.eventdate)
            ELSE max(t2.eventdate) 
       END as eventdate
FROM PARENT p
JOIN TABLE1 t1
  ON p.id = t1.id
JOIN TABLE2 t2
  ON p.id = t2.id
GROUP BY p.label
```

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use `union all` followed by aggregation.  The following does this with a twist, which is to pre-aggregate the results on each table:

```
select p.label, max(maxed) as max_eventdate
from ((select parentid, max(eventdate) as maxed
       from table1
       group by parentid
      ) union all
      (select parentid, max(eventdate)
       from table2
       group by parentid
      )
     ) t12 join
     parent p
     on t12.parentid = p.id
group by p.label;
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a function `GREATEST()` just for this purpose, so you can adjust the solution proposed by @JuanCarlosOropeza:

```
SELECT label,  GREATEST(max(t1.eventdate), max(t2.eventdate)) eventdate
FROM PARENT p
JOIN TABLE1 t1 ON p.id = t1.id
JOIN TABLE2 t2 ON ON p.id = t2.id
GROUP BY p.label
```

You may want to use `LEFT JOIN` in case events may be present only in one of the two event tables.

Comment: Sound good, I know `GREATEST` exist on mySQL wasnt sure about db2

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - it's probably for compatibility with Oracle or something - you can use `MAX(...)` as a scalar function, too.